# Oracle VSS Writer vs. RMAN

Tags: oracle-11g, vss, rman

I am unable to find any literature to evaluate which solution to use when backing up my Oracle 11g DB. The attempt is to perform online backups by enabling ARCHIVELOG mode.

Edit: I have gone through individual documentation for RMAN and VSS Writer. I am looking for comparative analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has some documentation on the topic: [Performing Database Backup and Recovery with VSS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e10845/vss.htm#sthref345).

Both VSS and RMAN looks good to me, the main difference is how you can use it:

The main advantage of RMAN is the use of the catalog. It stores informations of the latest backups and allow to easily restore data.

VSS will work at a lower level, without your database being aware that it is backed-up. But VSS will allow you to backup your database using the same way (and tools) that you can use to backup a file server or an SQL-Server database.

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation you are looking for is [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28270.pdf), which documents how to backup Oracle 11g databases using the Recovery Manager (RMAN) tool. The documentation can also be found in HTML format [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28270/toc.htm)